# Can't get foreach in index page in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

I can't get my categories name in `indexpage` in laravel 5.5,

here is my controller:

```
public function leftmenu() {
      $categories = Category::orderby('id', 'desc')->take(9)->get();
      return view('frontend.slider', compact('categories'));
    }
```

my route:

```
Route::get('/slider', 'IndexController@leftmenu');
```

my layout:

```
@include('frontend.slider')
```

and my blade:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
<li class="nav-item _icon">
<a href="./collections-all.html">
<img src="{{asset('default/frontend/assets/images/home3_icon_electronics.png')}}" alt="electronics">
<span>{{$category->title}}</span>
</a>
</li>
@endforeach
```

Here is the error i get:

> Undefined variable: categories (View:
>   C:\laragon\www\xxxxxxxx\resources\views\frontend\slider.blade.php)
>   (View:
>   C:\laragon\www\xxxxxxxx\resources\views\frontend\slider.blade.php)
>   (View:
>   C:\laragon\www\xxxxxxxx\resources\views\frontend\slider.blade.php)

Comment: echo or print in your blade file and check view file is loading or not

Comment: where did you put `@include('frontend.slider')`

Comment: @Maraboc in layout file also i moved it to index but result were the same.

Comment: you have not passed your $categories to slider, Nor $categories is a global variable to slider. That's why it is showing undefined variable

Comment: is your slider.blade is in frontend directory?

Comment: @DushantSingh what is your solution?

Comment: @Rits yes it is

Comment: frontend in dir other ?

Comment: @Mohammad is in views folder

Comment: So why is this used? ```@include('frontend.slider')```

Comment: @Mohammad because i added  include in my layout and not index.blade

Comment: you ```return view('frontend.slider', compact('categories'));``` in ```return view('index', compact('categories'));``` and using ```@include('frontend.slider', compact('categories'))```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a view composer, in the `app > Providers > ComposerServiceProvider` in the boot method add :

```
View::composer('frontend.slider', function ($view) {
    $categories = Category::orderby('id', 'desc')->take(9)->get();
    $view->with('categories', $categories);
});
```

**Why ?**

Because you include the slider in the layout so if you visit just the home page you will see the slider the problem here is that you call `leftmenu` when visiting `/slider` not the home page where the categories not exists.

Comment: where is that `ComposerServiceProvider `?

Comment: @mafortis in ```app > Providers > ComposerServiceProvider```

Comment: @maraboc is there anyway to i load my categories without loading in providers? cause next i need to load my posts from different categories as well!

Comment: is the slider will be viewed from all the pages or just onece ? and the posts are they needed in the slider ?